# How to remove multiple empty lines when scraping with Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

my code outputs multiple empty line breaks. 
How do i remove all the empty space?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import re
url = input('enter url moish')
page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page,'lxml')
all = soup.find_all('a', {'class' : re.compile('itemIncludes')})
for i in all:
          print(i.text)
```

code output:

```
Canon EOS 77D DSLR Camera (Body Only)



LP-E17 Lithium-Ion Battery Pack



LC-E17 Charger for LP-E17 Battery Pack
```

desired output:

```
Canon EOS 77D DSLR Camera (Body Only)
LP-E17 Lithium-Ion Battery Pack
LC-E17 Charger for LP-E17 Battery Pack
```

Thanks!

Comment: could we see an example url?

Answer (score 2):

You could remove empty lines before printing:

```
items = [item.text for item in all if item.text.strip() != '']
```

Comment: Nice and clean!

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in all:
           items = ' '.join(i.text.split())
           print(items)
```

the code above removed all the white spaces

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex to filter the output, something like:

```
import re
text = i.text.strip()
if not re.search(r"^\s+$", text): # if not a bank line
    print(text)
```

---

Note:

1. This is just a fix for the output since the problem may reside on
   the `find_all` arguments, which I cannot test.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you've solved this by now, but I'm brand new to python and had the same issue. I also didn't want to just remove the lines when printing, I wanted to change them in the element, this was my solution

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(getPage())
elements = soup.findAll()

for element in elements:
    text = element.text.strip()
    element.string = re.sub(r"[\n][\W]+[^\w]", "\n", text)

print(soup)
```

Loops through elements, gets the text, replace any instance of "\n followed by whitespace, but nothing else>" (one way to find empty lines, but feel free to use a better one!), sets the replaced value back into the element.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in all:
      print(i.stripped_strings)
```

had a similar problem, couldn't find a solution.
then this worked!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).